# How to convert a float into time?

Tags: c#

As an example lets say I have `float total_Time = 228.10803` what I want is to convert `total_Time` into a time format so it would look like this `00:03:48` how would I do that?

I thought of writing it like this:

```
{

    float total_Time = 0;
    float h = 0;
    float m = 0;
    float s = 0;

    br.BaseStream.Position = i + 4;
    total_Time = br.ReadSingle(); //reads 228.10803
    total_Time = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Round(total_Time, 0));
    if (total_Time < 3600)
    {
        h = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        h = total_Time / 3600;
        h = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Round(h, 0));
        total_Time = total_Time - (h * 3600);
    }
    m = total_Time / 60;
    m = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Round(m, 0));
    total_Time = total_Time - (m * 60);
    s = total_Time;
    s = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Round(s, 0));
    SaveCS_PlayTime.Text = String.Format("Play Time: {0}:{1}:{2}", h, m, s);
}
```

But for some reason it shows it like this `00:4:-12`. Maybe I have made a mistake. Really need some help with this. I know there are posts with practically same titles as mine but non had the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like you should convert it into a `TimeSpan` and then format that:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        float totalSeconds = 228.10803f;
        TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds);
        Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss")); // 00:03:48
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library, where you'd construct a [`Duration`](http://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.Duration.html) and then format that.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. If you wouldn't mind could you also answer this question for me, how would I convert time to float? I made it so you can edit play time and have 3 text boxes labeled (Hour, Minute, Second) so if someone was to type in 2, 15, 7 and I would make it a string like this `02:15:07` how would I convert that into float?

Comment: @Gecko45444: Well, I'd personally probably parse all three as integers and do simple arithmetic.

Comment: oh, ok. Will give that a try. Thanks again for answering my initial question. :)

Comment: @Gecko45444 `(float)TimeSpan.Parse("02:15:07").TotalSeconds`

Answer (score 0):

To answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379541/how-to-convert-a-float-into-time#comment79717893_46379617), here's how you could use "plain" math to get the time string:

```
var totalSeconds =  228.10803;
var ss = Convert.ToInt32(totalSeconds % 60).ToString("00");
var mm = (Math.Floor(totalSeconds / 60) % 60).ToString("00");
var hh = Math.Floor(totalSeconds / 60 / 60).ToString("00");
Console.WriteLine(hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss);
```